# how to load mysql jar in shell script and connect to MYSQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, linux, shell

I have written a small shell script to invoke a java class , which inturn invokes mysql db and returns some resultset.

## My Shell Scipt:

```
CP="."
CP=$CP:/home/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar
export CP
java -cp $CP com.util.Hello
```

and my java code is as follows,

## Hello.Java:

```
public static void main(String[] str) {
 Connection conn = null;
          try
          {
              String userName = "root";
              String password = "root";
              String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
              Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
              conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, userName, password);
              System.out.println ("Database connection established");

                Statement s = conn.createStatement ();
                s.executeQuery ("select * from users");
                ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet ();
                int count = 0;
                while (rs.next ())
                {                       
                    System.out.println (count + " rows were retrieved");
                    count++;    
                }
                    rs.close ();
                    s.close ();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
             System.err.println ("Cannot connect to database server")
        }

}
```

when i execute shell script from linux server i am getting below error,

Cannot connect to database server which i have printed in my java class

```
System.err.println ("Cannot connect to database server")
```

can some help me in how to load mysql jar from shells script ?

and how to use it while running my java class?

if i run this class from war file its working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be much easier to tell what the problem is if you didn't catch and then discard the exception.  Do this.  Remove the try/catch block, add "throws Exception" to the main method declaration, run again, and then post the entire stack trace (error message).

Comment: Also remove the 'newInstance ()' part. You just need to load the class using: Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Answer (score 0):

You need but **mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar** in your **/jre/lib/ext** folder in java jre folder i think this is easy way to run your java database program